# Como mostar apenas metade do conteudo que a camera pega?

Tags: python

Gostaria de saber como mostrar o conteúdo capturado via webcam (pelo vídeoCapture) em uma janela que apenas mostrasse metade do que a camera pega, Em opencv.

Answer (score 1):

Basta você obter o tamanho da imagem utilizando o atributo `shape` e depois recortar a imagem utilizando `slice` (sua imagem é um objeto de [numpy.ndarray](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/numpy-ndarray/), que é uma espécie de lista). Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
import cv2
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
r, frame = camera.read()

height, width = frame.shape[0:2]  # Obtém altura e largura da imagem
height //= 2                      # Corta a imagem no meio

# Obtém uma parte da imagem que vai de Y[0 - height] X[0 - width]
new_frame = frame[0:height, 0:width] 

cv2.imshow("Imagem Cortada", new_frame)
```

Comment: Tente rodar esse codigo e recebi esse erro " new_frame = frame[0:height, 0:width]
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method"

Comment: Opa, cometi um erro no código e já corrigi o problema. O erro estava sendo causado porque ao dividir o `height` o resultado era um `float`, e não é possível utilizar float's no slice. Tente rodar esse código novamente

Comment: Realmente esse novo codigo funciona, mas por questão de aprofundamento se eu quissese pegar a outra metada o lado oposto seria possivel?

Comment: Claro que sim, basta fazer uma calculo simples. Para obter a metade de cima, você deve começar do ponto ZERO até a metade da tela ( `height / 2` ), logo, para obter a outra metade basta começar da metade da tela ( `height / 2` ) até o tamanho da máximo da tela que é o `height`.

Comment: E como eu faria isso no codigo?

Comment: Substitua a linha 8 por `new_frame = frame[height: height * 2, 0:width]`